# Identifying the specific PDF field type with iText7

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

Using this PDF form example:
http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf

This code:

```
public String getPdfFieldNames() throws IOException {
    if (pdf == null || pdf.isClosed()) {
        throwPdfNotOpenException();
    }
    if (getPdfFormType().equals("XFA")) {
        throwXfaNotSupportedException();
    }

    String s = "";
    Map<String, PdfFormField> map = form.getFormFields();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        String simpleFieldType = getSimpleFieldType(form.getField(key));
        s += "[Field name: " + key + ", Field type: " + simpleFieldType + "]\n";
    }
    s = (s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));

    return s;
}
private String getSimpleFieldType(PdfFormField field) {
    if (field.getFormType() == PdfName.Tx) {
        return "text box";
    } else if (field.getFormType() == PdfName.Ch) {
        return "check box";
    } else if (field.getFormType() == PdfName.Btn) {
        return "button";
    } else {
        return field.getFormType().toString();
    }
    // also do radio button
}
```

Produces these results:

```
    [Field name: Given Name Text Box, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: Family Name Text Box, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: Address 1 Text Box, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: House nr Text Box, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: Address 2 Text Box, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: Postcode Text Box, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: City Text Box, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: Country Combo Box, Field type: check box]
    [Field name: Gender List Box, Field type: check box]
    [Field name: Height Formatted Field, Field type: text box]
    [Field name: Driving License Check Box, Field type: button]
    [Field name: Language 1 Check Box, Field type: button]
    [Field name: Language 2 Check Box, Field type: button]
    [Field name: Language 3 Check Box, Field type: button]
    [Field name: Language 4 Check Box, Field type: button]
    [Field name: Language 5 Check Box, Field type: button]
    [Field name: Favourite Colour List Box, Field type: check box]
```

As you can see text boxes are correct but drop down lists are being considered check boxes and check boxes are being considered buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to identify the specific field types.

The updated methods:

```
    public String getPdfFieldNames() throws IOException {
    if (pdf == null || pdf.isClosed()) {
        throwPdfNotOpenException();
    }
    if (getPdfFormType().equals("XFA")) {
        throwXfaNotSupportedException();
    }

    String s = "";
    Map<String, PdfFormField> map = form.getFormFields();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        PdfName type = form.getField(key).getFormType();
        String simpleFieldType = getSimpleFieldType(form.getField(key), type, key);
        s += "[Field name: " + key + ", Field type: " + simpleFieldType + "]\n";

    }
    s = (s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));

    return s;
}

private String getSimpleFieldType(PdfFormField field, PdfName type, String key) {

     if (0 == PdfName.Btn.compareTo(type)) {
         if(((PdfButtonFormField)form.getField(key)).isPushButton()){
             return "Push Button";
         } else {
             if(((PdfButtonFormField)form.getField(key)).isRadio()){
                 return "Radio Button";                   
             }else {
                 return "Check Box";
             }
         }
     } else if (0 == PdfName.Ch.compareTo(type)) {
         return "List Box";
     } else if (0 == PdfName.Sig.compareTo(type)) {
         return "Signature";
     } else if (0 == PdfName.Tx.compareTo(type)) {
         return "Text Box";

     }else {
         return "Unknown type";
     }
}
```

The results now display as:

```
[Field name: Given Name Text Box, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: Family Name Text Box, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: Address 1 Text Box, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: House nr Text Box, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: Address 2 Text Box, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: Postcode Text Box, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: City Text Box, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: Country Combo Box, Field type: List Box]
[Field name: Gender List Box, Field type: List Box]
[Field name: Height Formatted Field, Field type: Text Box]
[Field name: Driving License Check Box, Field type: Check Box]
[Field name: Language 1 Check Box, Field type: Check Box]
[Field name: Language 2 Check Box, Field type: Check Box]
[Field name: Language 3 Check Box, Field type: Check Box]
[Field name: Language 4 Check Box, Field type: Check Box]
[Field name: Language 5 Check Box, Field type: Check Box]
[Field name: Favourite Colour List Box, Field type: List Box]
```

Answer (score 1):

iText 7 returns the correct type, merely your code

```
private String getSimpleFieldType(PdfFormField field) {
    if (field.getFormType() == PdfName.Tx) {
        return "text box";
    } else if (field.getFormType() == PdfName.Ch) {
        return "check box";
    } else if (field.getFormType() == PdfName.Btn) {
        return "button";
    } else {
        return field.getFormType().toString();
    }
    // also do radio button
}
```

interprets the information incorrectly.

`getFormType` returns the form field type name according to the PDF specification, and ISO 32000-2 describes the field type in Table 226 *Entries common to all field dictionaries*:

> The type of field that this dictionary describes:
>
> *Btn* Button (see 12.7.5.2, "Button fields")
>
> *Tx* Text (see 12.7.5.3, "Text fields")
>
> *Ch* Choice (see 12.7.5.4, "Choice fields")
>
> *Sig* (PDF 1.3) Signature (see 12.7.5.5, "Signature fields")

So `PdfName.Ch` indicates a choice field and `PdfName.Btn` indicates any flavor of a button field; again according to ISO 32000-2, this time section 12.7.5.2 *Button fields*:

> A *button field* (field type *Btn*) represents an interactive control on the screen that the user can manipulate with the mouse. There are three types of button fields:
>
> - A *push-button* is a purely interactive control that responds immediately to user input without retaining a permanent value (see 12.7.5.2.2, "Push-buttons").
> - A *check box* toggles between two states, on and off (see 12.7.5.2.3, "Check boxes").
> - *Radio button fields* contain a set of related buttons that can each be on or off. Typically, at most one radio button in a set may be on at any given time, and selecting any one of the buttons automatically deselects all the others. (There are exceptions to this rule, as noted in 12.7.5.2.4, "Radio buttons")

Comment: Interesting. There isn't any documentation on the field types so I gathered them by using the getFormType method on known field types and worked backwards from that. So are you saying that all the field types are too generic to do what I'm trying to do or are there more specific types available?

Comment: more information can be gathered from other field properties. Merely the field type is fairly generic.